# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2> android studio sqlite database

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

```
`package com.example.wheresnapped;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataManager {

    // the actual apps database
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // public static final string for each row of the table that we need
    // to refer both inside and outside this class

    public static final String TABLE_ROW_ID = "_id";
    public static final String TABLE_ROW_TITLE = "image_title";
    public static final String TABLE_ROW_URI = "image_uri";

    // private ones that we need to refer to just from within this class

    private static final String DB_NAME = "w_snap_db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_PHOTOS = "ws_table_photos";
    private static final String TABLE_TAGS = "ws_table_tags";
    private static final String TABLE_ROW_TAG1 = "tag1";
    private static final String TABLE_ROW_TAG2 = "tag2";
    private static final String TABLE_ROW_TAG3 = "tag3";
    public static final String TABLE_ROW_TAG = "tag";      // for the tags table

    public DataManager(Context context){
        CustomSQLITEOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLITEOpenHelper(context);

        // get a writable database
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void addPhoto(Photo photo){
        // add all the details to the photos table
        String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_PHOTOS +" (" +
                TABLE_ROW_TITLE + ", " +
                TABLE_ROW_URI + ", " +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG1 + ", " +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG2 + ", " +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG3 + ") " +
                "VALUES (" +
                "'" + photo.getTitle() +"'" + ", " +
                "'" + photo.getStorageLocation() + "'" + ", " +
                "'" + photo.getTag1() + "'" + ", " +
                "'" + photo.getTag2() + "'" + ", " +
                "'" + photo.getTag3() + "'" + ", " +
                ");";

        Log.i("addPhoto()", query);
        db.execSQL(query);

        // add any new tags to the tags table

        query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TAGS + "(" +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG + ") " +
                "SELECT '" + photo.getTag1() + "' " +
                "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM )" +
                TABLE_TAGS +
                " WHERE " + TABLE_ROW_TAG + " = " +
                "'" + photo.getTag1() +"');";

        db.execSQL(query);

        query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TAGS + "(" +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG + ") " +
                "SELECT '" + photo.getTag2() + "' " +
                "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM )" +
                TABLE_TAGS +
                " WHERE " + TABLE_ROW_TAG + " = " +
                "'" + photo.getTag2() +"');";

        db.execSQL(query);

        query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TAGS + "(" +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG + ") " +
                "SELECT '" + photo.getTag3() + "' " +
                "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM )" +
                TABLE_TAGS +
                " WHERE " + TABLE_ROW_TAG + " = " +
                "'" + photo.getTag3() +"');";

        db.execSQL(query);

    }

    public Cursor getTitles(){
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + TABLE_ROW_ID + ", " +
                TABLE_ROW_TITLE + "from " + TABLE_PHOTOS, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }

    public Cursor getTitlesWithTag(String tag){
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + TABLE_ROW_ID + ", " +
                TABLE_ROW_TITLE + " from " +
                TABLE_PHOTOS + " WHERE " +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG1 + " = '" + tag + "' or " +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG2 + " = '" + tag + "' or " +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG3 + " = '" + tag + "';", null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }

    public Cursor getPhoto(int id){

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " +
                TABLE_PHOTOS +
                " WHERE " +
                TABLE_ROW_ID + " = " + id, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }

    // returns all the tags for our fragment class
    public Cursor getTags(){
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + TABLE_ROW_ID + ", " +
                TABLE_ROW_TAG + " from " + TABLE_TAGS, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }

    // class is created when our DataManager is initialized
    private class CustomSQLITEOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public CustomSQLITEOpenHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        // only runs the first time the database is created
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            // create table for photos and all their details
            String newTableQueryString = "create table "
                    + TABLE_PHOTOS + " ("
                    +TABLE_ROW_ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
                    + TABLE_ROW_TITLE
                    + " text not null,"
                    + TABLE_ROW_URI
                    + " text not null,"
                    + TABLE_ROW_TAG1
                    + " text not null,"
                    + TABLE_ROW_TAG2
                    + " text not null,"
                    + TABLE_ROW_TAG3
                    + " text not null" + ");";

            db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);

            // create a separate table for tags
            newTableQueryString = "create table "
                    + TABLE_TAGS + " ("
                    + TABLE_ROW_ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
                    + TABLE_ROW_TAG
                    + " text not null" + ");";

            db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);
        }

        // method only runs when we increment db version
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
}
```

`
[image: my entire logcat output and code to create database tables]

i am working on an app to fetch data from an sqlite database android, my code has got no errors or warnings but the app crashes on launch with the messages on the image shown on the log window. i searched for the error to do with sql and cant seem to find any error with my database creation code which i've also attached. any help with this could be really appreciated